# How to make add a dropdown in blazor's sweetalerts2

Tags: c#, blazor, sweetalert2

I am currently making some changes to a website and wanted to add a dropdown to a sweetalert2 element but can't seem to figure out how the inputvalidator field should be completed

I mostly tried different approaches but none of them seem to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.